# Drawing thousand of lines using PIXI.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, opengl-es-2.0, pixi.js

I'm creating a demo using quadtrees and I have thousand of circles colliding against other thousands. This works fine but I'm having trouble optimizing the way I draw the lines since I can't use sprites for this, can I?

How should I go about drawing thousands of lines that will surely differ in length, angle and must be recreated/destroyed on every frame?

Right now what I have is the following:

```
this.line = new PIXI.Graphics().lineStyle(1, 0x3F51B5, 0.75);
this.container.addChild(this.line);
.
.
.
loop(){
   this.line.clear();
   this.line.lineStyle(1, 0x3F51B5, 0.75);
   for(...){
      circle1 = circles1[i];
      for(...){
      circle2 = circles2[j];
         this.line.moveto(circle1.x, circle1.y).linteTo(circle2.x, circle2.y)
      }
   }       
}
```

Comment: Recreating and destroying them on every frame sounds like a bad idea, you should instead find a way to modify them. How much do they differ between every frame, could you just manipulate sprite sizes (scale them) or create multiple different sprites and reuse or clone them?

Comment: @Hachi it's basically a set of points colliding against another set of points. When two points get close a line is drawn connecting them, showing that they're close. As you can see the lines will differ in length and angle not sure if I could sprite that.

Comment: It sounds potentially difficult performance-wise. I'm not familiar enough how graphics-objects work internally, so I would recommend finding for some posts relate to graphics-objects optimization or how to reuse them here: http://www.html5gamedevs.com or just ask. It's an interesting case performance-wise anyway :).